# Requires API level 21 (current min is 16)

Tags: java, android, android-camera

I'm new in android development and programming. I'm working on android camera application. I'm new in this so I use the lectures of a youtuber who uses API level 21 and I'm using API level 16 for maximum users but our code is same which causes a problem.

[image]

call requires API level 21 (current min is `16):android.hardware.camera2.CameraDevice.StateCallback#StateCallback` more...<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>f1</kbd>)

Please help me to fix this. I don't want to change its API level to 21.

Comment: please see this link : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraDevice.StateCallback.html  In the documentation is clear that `CameraDevice.StateCallback` is added in `API LEVEL 21` if you won't use this then your minSDKVersion is you have to set is `21`.

Comment: *"i'm don't want to change its API level to 21"*  - Well .... it should be clear that you will need to find a different tutorial / lecture / whatever to help you learn to use the camera.  For example: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidCamera/article.html

Comment: Then you need to use the older camera api.  THe newer one exists only in v21+

Answer (score 2):

Use 'android.hardware.camera' instead of 'android.hardware.camera2' API and that allows you to use that API with API level 16.

Comment: import android.hardware.camera2.CameraDevice;